# Upper bound for tuple of exponents of prime factorization

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

Let $a(n)$ be the $k$-ary tuple of the exponents of the prime factorization of $n$. For example,

$$a(5184)=a(2^{6}⋅3^{4})=(6, 4), a(65536)=a(2^{16})=(16).$$

Formally, let $p_{1}^{a_{1}}, p_{2}^{a_{2}}, \ldots, p_{k}^{a_{k}}$ be the prime factorization of a positive integer $n$, then

$$a(n) = a(p_{1}^{a_{1}}, p_{2}^{a_{2}}, \ldots, p_{k}^{a_{k}}) = (a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{k}).$$

Let $|\ldots|$ be the bit-length function. For example,

$$|3| = 2,\qquad |10| = 4,\qquad |256| = 9.$$

We define the bit-length of a $k$-ary tuple $(a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{k})$ as $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}(|a_{i}| + 1)$.

Question: Is $|a(n)| = O(log(|n|))$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unfortunate to use the notation $|\cdot|$ for the bit-length function, because in number theory (where this post belongs) it denotes the absolute value function. At any rate, in standard notation, you are asking if
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\lfloor 1+\log_2 a_i\rfloor\ll\log\log n. $$
The answer is no, even if we replace the terms on the left hand side by $\log_2 a_i$. Indeed, let $p_2<p_3<\dots$ be the sequence of primes, and consider $n=p_1^2\dots p_k^2$. Then by the Prime Number Theorem we have
$$ \log n=2(\log p_1+\dots+\log p_k)\sim 2p_k\sim 2k\log k,$$
hence
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\log_2 a_i = k \sim \frac{\log n}{2\log\log n},$$
which grows much faster than $\log\log n$.

Comment: Actually, $|w|$ *is* a standard notation for the length of a string over a finite alphabet, and by the same token, of the binary representation of an integer. Please, don’t make the mistake of assuming that your area of mathematics is all of mathematics.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Thanks for pointing this out. I don't assume that my area of mathematics is all of mathematics. The post appeared under the nt.number-theory tag, which is actually my area. I do believe, and I think most users would agree with me, that using the standard notation $|w|$ for the length of a string over a finite alphabet is very misleading when it is applied for a positive integer $w$ in a number theory post. At any rate, I updated the first sentence in my post.

Comment: I do agree the notation is unfortunate in a number theory post. My complaint was about your generalization “everywhere in mathematics ...” that you now removed from the post (thank you). Note that the OP may not be aware that the notation is uncommon in number theory if he has a background in a different field where it is common. The possibility to ask questions from a different field than your own is one of the important goals of MO.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yes, my remark was not appropriate, so thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Isn't your definition of "bit length" off by one? The bit length of $2^n$ is not $n$, it is $n+1$ (check with 2^1).

Comment: @joro: Yes, the bit-length of $a_i$ is $\lfloor 1+\log_2 a_i\rfloor$, e.g. $\lfloor 1+\log_2 2^n\rfloor=n+1$ in harmony with what you say, and this is what I indicated in my first display.

Comment: More succinctly, the a value of the kth primorial is k, while  the bit length of that primorial is less than k^2 for k > 1, and so log of that bit length doesn't beat k. Gerhard "Likes Short And Simple Arguments" Paseman, 2016.12.08.